# Yeoman outputs warnings running a generator

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator, yo, shelljs

I am implementing a Yeoman generator, it works but when I run it I am getting a lot of undesired warnings as shown in this image:

[image: Undesired warnings running Yo generator]

I created the most basics generator in Javascript, it only contains the package.json, the *index.js* in the **generators/app** folder and a folder named *templates* with a single HTML file inside.

In the image I use *PowerShell* but I have used *Git Bash* also to run the Yo command, I have tried in **Windows 10 and 11, I tried Node 14.20.0 and 16.16.0 and the version of Yeoman is 4.3.0**. I read several posts about the cause being the [shelljs](https://github.com/yeoman/yo/issues/652) but that library gets installed with just the following dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "generator-diego",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "First Yo generator",
  "files": [
    "generators"
  ],
  "keywords": [
    "yeoman-generator"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "yeoman-generator": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Here the code of my generator:

```
var Generator = require('yeoman-generator');

module.exports = class extends Generator {
  constructor(args, opts) {
    super(args, opts);
    this.option("default");
  }

  async prompting() {
      this.answers = await this.prompt([
        {
          type    : 'input',
          name    : 'appName',
          message : 'Your application name: ',
          when: !this.options.default
        }
      ]);
    }

    writing() {
      if (this.options.default) {
        this.answers = { appName: 'auto-app' }; // Set a default answer, more can be added
      }

      this.fs.copyTpl(
        this.templatePath('basic-template'),
        this.destinationPath(this.answers.appName),
        {
            appName: this.answers.appName
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

Does anybody knows how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These warnings appear due to the versions you are using for node and Yeoman-generator. Upgrading Yeoman-generator to the latest version should solve the problem.
Also, it would be a good practice. That version is very old.
I hope it helps.

Comment: Hey @Lorenzo Fay, thanks a lot that did the trick!